# How can I modify code with subplots into a live animation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graphing

I have recently moved back into learning python for its use of `matplotlib` and ability to plot data nicely.

I decided to give myself a basic project to plot two visualisations. The first would be the total rolls for each face on a six-sided die, in the form of a bar graph.

the second plot would be a simple scatter graph displaying the roll-by-roll of each face rolled. Meaning, it would display the output of rolls responsible for the first plot.

I managed this so far, and achieved a nice result, however, I would like to animate each roll onto both of the plots, but this is something I have had a lot of trouble with so far.

Currently, my basic code is as follows:

```py
import random 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate a plot displaying two elements:
# One: Display 6 side die roll results
# Two: Plot the order of rolls

numRolls = 100

rollTotals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
rollSeq = []

for roll in range(numRolls):
  currentRoll = random.randint(1, 6)
  rollTotals[currentRoll - 1] += 1
  rollSeq.append(currentRoll)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.bar([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], rollTotals, 1/1.5)
plt.title("Roll Totals")

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(rollSeq)
plt.title("Roll Sequence")

plt.show()
```

`numRolls` is a constant to allow a quick variable change to the number of dice rolls.
`rollTotals` is a 6 element list of values used to represent the total number of rolls for each side of the die.
`rollSeq` is a list to show the order of each roll.

As you can see, I have a basic script to immediately simulate and output the results as a subplot. I have looked into the animation side of `matplotlib`, but I am unable to figure out how exactly to work everything together to animate correctly and smoothly.

Thank you for your assistance in helping me further my hobby.

Comment: I suggest you start with animating something very simple (say, one sine curve) and go from there.

Comment: @gmds I have already read through matplotlib's [animation](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) documentation. I understand it well enough for a single plot. I just have no idea how this translates into something with two plots.

Comment: It's the same thing for two plots. You have a function which is called repeatedly (assuming you're using `FuncAnimation`) that modifies artists each call. You just have to modify artists on *both* axes in the same function.

Comment: @gmds Hmm, I see. I will keep playing around with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After looking through like, 20 different posts, and re-reading the documentation at least 10 times, I have come up with this:

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Generate a plot displaying two elements:
# One: Display 6 side die roll results
# Two: Plot the order of rolls

numRolls = 300

rollTotals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
rollSeq = []

# Create a figure with two subplots
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

# Adjust spacing between plots
plt.subplots_adjust(top = 0.93, bottom = 0.07, hspace = 0.3)

#define the function for use in matplotlib.animation.funcAnimation
def animate(i):

    currentRoll = random.randint(1, 6)
    rollTotals[currentRoll - 1] += 1
    rollSeq.append(currentRoll)

    # Set subplot data
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.bar([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], rollTotals, 1/1.5)

    ax2.clear()
    ax2.plot(rollSeq)
    xlim = len(rollSeq)
    ax2.set_xlim(xlim - 30, xlim)

    # Set subplot titles
    ax1.set_title("Roll Totals")
    ax2.set_title("Roll Sequence")


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=numRolls, interval=50, repeat=False)

# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

# Save ani
ani.save(r'D:\_Data\Desktop\AnimationOutput.mp4', writer=writer)

#plt.show()
```

This could be optimised by using Blitting in the `animation.FuncAnimation`, but it is more confusing. As it is, this can probably be further optimised. ALSO, I figured out how to save the animation as an mp4.

If you don't want to export, uncomment `plt.show()` and remove everything else under `ani = animation.FuncAnimation(...)`